# Git: Unstaged changes went up

Tags: git

I was pushing *some* commits and then wanted to stage the other files next for another commit, but instead the push pushed the unstaged files too .. What did I do wrong? How did unstaged commits go up with a push?

```
kirk:bear.com kirk$ git status
# On branch development
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
# modified:   app/fonts/bear.eot
# modified:   app/fonts/bear.otf
# modified:   app/fonts/bear.svg
# modified:   app/fonts/bear.ttf
# modified:   app/fonts/bear.woff
# modified:   app/styles/global/text/bear/glyphs.less
# modified:   app/views/partials/global/actions.html
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
# modified:   app/styles/core/components.less
# modified:   app/styles/core/container.less
#
kirk:bear.com kirk$ git commit -a
[development 254d21c] fix(Style): Add "followers" and "following" icon as new three people icon. Switched "following" icon in "Me" modal.
 9 files changed, 18 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)
 rewrite app/fonts/bear.eot (80%)
 rewrite app/fonts/bear.otf (99%)
 rewrite app/fonts/bear.svg (99%)
 rewrite app/fonts/bear.ttf (78%)
 rewrite app/fonts/bear.woff (99%)
kirk:bear.com kirk$ git push
Counting objects: 39, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (19/19), done.
Writing objects: 100% (20/20), 33.09 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 20 (delta 13), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@github.com:BigBear/bear.com.git
   c70ca7c..254d21c  development -> development
kirk:bear.com kirk$ git status
# On branch development
nothing to commit, working directory clean
kirk:bear.com kirk$ git status
# On branch development
nothing to commit, working directory clean
kirk:bear.com kirk$
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You didn't have any unstaged changes. `git commit -a` stages all changes prior to committing. You wanted simply `git commit` to commit on the previously staged changes.

Answer (score 2):

These might be ***unstaged*** files, but they are not ***untracked*** :

```
# modified:   app/styles/core/components.less
# modified:   app/styles/core/container.less
```

From the man page for git-commit:

```
-a
--all
Tell the command to automatically stage files that have been modified and deleted,
but new files you have not told git about are not affected.
```

When you did `git commit -a`, you grabbed those as well. Git already knows about them.

Answer (score 2):

`git commit -a` automatically stages all changed (and tracked) files before committing them.

See the ["Skipping the Staging Area" section in the "Pro Git" book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository).